# Rename command not working as expected

Tags: rename

I might be overlooking something really basic here but I have a bunch of files like

```
fi-le_00.nc2 fi-le_01.nc2 fi-le_02.nc2 ... fi-le_24.nc2
```

and I want to rename them to

```
fi-le_00:00:00 fi-le_01:00:00 fi-le_02:00:00 ... fi-le_24:00:00
```

so I am trying the command

```
rename 's/\.nc2$/:00:00/g' fi-le*
```

but nothing is happening. I have also tried `'s/\.nc2/:00:00/g'` and `'s/.nc2/:00:00/g'`, but as expected this also didn't work.

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your glob `file*` doesn't match `fi-le`...?

Comment: oh, sorry, that's a typo. The actual name was very long so I shortened it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found out the reason it wasn't working is because in the machine I'm working there is a weird version of rename whose syntax is actually `rename from to files*`. Hadn't seen that one before.

Comment: On Linux there are at least three different programs named `rename`.  The one you mention seems to be the `rename(1)` from `util-linux`. You probably want a Perl script version, which is sometimes named `prename`.

Comment: @lcd047 Is there an alternative command that I can use that is sure to be the same in every Linux distro? Cause I assume we have an issue much like find (which is the same in every distro) and locate (which differs).

Comment: I have no idea, sorry, but I'm probably not the right person to ask.  I'm not using Linux much these days.